# Unable to view tree as horizontal

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create tree horizontally.

I got one link http://codepen.io/Pestov/pen/BLpgm but it's not horizontal. I tried to change `css` but unable to get expected view. could anyone please tell me how can i do it to view tree as horizontal. root start from left.

I want css for below image..and it should be dynamic. as if nodes deleted then it should adjust edges.
[image: horizontal image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to rotate it?

Comment: yes..now root in on top. i want root is on left and childs will be in right side connected edges from left to right

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to just rotate `.tree` and then adjust `top` and `left` properties to position the tree as needed.

**EDITED:**

Add this to your css:

```
.tree {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: -50px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Add these to `.tree li a`:

```
.tree li a{
    margin: 45px 0;  // To accommodate space taken by each node
    transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    z-index: 10;
    background: white;
}
```

Add an `id` to one of the `ul` elements:

```
<a href="#">Parent</a>
<ul id="parent_root">
```

Then add this css:

```
#parent_root::before {
    height: 80px;
}
```

Finally, change the height here:

```
.tree ul ul::before{
    height: 100px; 
}
```

And the height here:

```
.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    height: 60px;
}}
```

**UPDATED CODEPEN:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOGNmE

Comment: I guess OP wants to rotate tree but not Nodes. I guess tree should be from left to right.

Comment: @snookieordie no it's not the correct. i don't want to rotate  nodes.

Comment: Add transform to each node element for rotation of + 90 degrees. This will cause the nodes to overlap. So have a javascript function which adds appropriate margin to each <a> element

Comment: @D_Supreme your edit is close to answer. You can add an answer yourself and explain the changes. Also, tree is not properly connected. Fix that and it would be complete

Comment: trying to make changes. but not getting expected result

Comment: @Tipu Here is D_Supreme's changes. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzwqzcf5/). Should be good reference to complete.

Comment: @Tipu Ok, it's not the prettiest, but I've updated the codepen so that the nodes do not rotate, and so that the tree is connected.

Comment: actually it's not dynamic..if i add nodes then it's not adjusting other divs

Answer (score 2):

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dsupreme/24vs99d3/

Add the following css:

```
.tree {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;   \\ Increase if elements are being cut from the top
    left: -50px; \\ Decrease if tree is shifted to much to the right
    transform: rotate(-90deg); \\ To rotate the whole tree anti clockwise
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(90deg); \\ To rotate all the nodes clockwise
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Add this js utility

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($("a"), function() {
        var currWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).css("margin", (currWidth*0.5 ) + "px 0 " + (currWidth*0.5) + "px 0");
    });
});
```

**Note:**

This works for scenario where elements on the same name do not have same value because we measure the width of each node and then add margin to each `<a>` separately

Margin: Top Right Bottom Left
We are giving top and bottom margin for aligning Left and Right because top and bottom when rotated by 90 degrees become properties for left and right